# Send multiple files to JS object and prepare for Ajax post

Tags: javascript, jquery

Check the code bellow. Here i am trying to insert files to js object then send to backend mvc5 controller to further processing. But problem is that when i when i trigger `#btn-HighlightUpdate` click jquery throws error in console says: `jquery-3.3.1.js:8463 Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation`. How can i fix it and prepare to send via ajax post? Specially plz check if i am inserting proper value to object on line `var file = $(this).find(".hpicFile");   data.push({ Img: file });`

Html:

```
<div class="row" id="hbar">
</div>
<div class="card-footer" style="text-align:right;">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary" id="btn-Newbar">New Bar</button>
    <button class="btn btn-secondary" id="btn-HighlightUpdate">Update Changes</button>
</div>
```

Dynamic Html:

```
$("#btn-Newbar").on("click", function () {
    $("#hbar").append("<div class='col-4 wholeBar' style='margin-bottom:20px;'><div class='row'><div class='col-3'><img src='' class='catHpic' style='height:80px;width:80px;'></div><div class='col-9'><input type='file' class='hpicFile'><div class='input-group mb-3' style='margin-top:10px;'><div class='input-group-prepend'><span class='input-group-text url'>URL</span></div><input type='text' class='form-control hurl' aria-describedby='basic-addon1' value=''></div></div></div></div>");
});
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).on("click", "#btn-HighlightUpdate", function () {
    var data = [];
    //data.push({ "Img": "fff" });

    $(".wholeBar").each(function (key, value) {
        var file = $(this).find(".hpicFile");
        data.push({ Img: file });
    });

    console.log(data);

    $.post('/Controller/UploadFiles', { Files: data }).done(function (data) {

        console.log(data);

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use to `$.ajax` to with type `POST` to send data to your controller.

I have fixed up your code which needed a [formData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData) to store all `files` (img's) found which we are adding `dynamically`. We can append those img found to the formData and send that formData your controller for further processing.

There is **no** need to use an `array` to `push` img into it. You can all that on the front end and in the controller just get all files which we are sending and `append` them to `formData`.

You were also not sending the correct files but `instead` your were sending the actual `HTML` element using `.find` function. To send the `actual object` to your controller you need to to use `findFiles[0].files[0]` and append that to the `formData` in your $.each function.

I have added some `comments` for you well on each line of code.

**Live Demo:**

```js
$("#btn-Newbar").on("click", function() {
  $("#hbar").append("<div class='col-4 wholeBar' style='margin-bottom:20px;'><div class='row'><div class='col-3'><img src='' class='catHpic' style='height:80px;width:80px;'></div><div class='col-9'><input type='file' class='hpicFile'><div class='input-group mb-3' style='margin-top:10px;'><div class='input-group-prepend'><span class='input-group-text url'>URL</span></div><input type='text' class='form-control hurl' aria-describedby='basic-addon1' value=''></div></div></div></div>");
});

//display highlight pic real time 
$(document).on("change", ".hpicFile", function(e) {
  var imgSrc = $(this).parent('div').prev().find('.catHpic') //find img
  if (e.target.files[0] != null) {
    //console.log(e.target.files[0]);
    $.each(this.files, function(key, file) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(e) {
        //display images real time
        imgSrc.attr('src', e.target.result);
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    });
  }
});

//Get all the files and send via ajax to your controller
$(document).on("click", "#btn-HighlightUpdate", function() {

  //FormData
  var formData = new FormData()

  $(".wholeBar").each(function(key, value) {
    var findFiles = $(this).find(".hpicFile") //find the element
    var file = findFiles[0].files[0] //get the actual file object
    formData.append('files[]', file) //append all files to formData
  });


  //Ajax request
  $.ajax({
    url: "/Controller/UploadFiles",
    type: "POST",
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    data: formData, //Send form Data
    success: function(response) {
      console.log(response)
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row" id="hbar">
</div>
<div class="card-footer" style="text-align:right;">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary" id="btn-Newbar">New Bar</button>
  <button class="btn btn-secondary" id="btn-HighlightUpdate">Update Changes</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you bro for your afford. You are great teacher

Comment: @Palmal No worries. Always Glad to help. Happy Coding!